# The difference between blackberry simulator for debug/run in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, blackberry

When i click **Run -> Debug Configuration** there will be a 3 different types of simuator :

1. blackberry simulator
2. blackberry  device and
3. blackberry simulator(running)

Which one should i use?

This is the picture :
[image]

And everytime i want to debug my code in the simulator(f11), the annoying question will be appear.  This is the picture :

[image]

**My questions are :**

1. which one should i use?
2. what is the different? and
3. is there any way to make the annoying question (2nd picture) never appear again?

(I dont know what the 2nd picture (dialog) is for. Although it keeps asking that question, i cant really *choose*, because only 1 choice will run smooth while the other 2 will make an error, so why is it asking?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had these problems, too.  It's not very clear.

Basically, **BlackBerry Device** would be for running on a real BlackBerry smartphone.  To choose this, obviously, you must have a BlackBerry smartphone connected.

As for the other two, I always use **BlackBerry Simulator** myself.  It sounds like **BlackBerry Simulator (running)** would be for running on a simulator that has already been started.  But, in my experience, choosing **BlackBerry Simulator** usually works, even if the simulator has already been started.  However, although there are several ways to do this within Eclipse (the normal Eclipse **Run / Debug** menus, the **BlackBerry** menu, or right clicking on the project in Eclipse's **Project Explorer**), I haven't always had good success with all of them.

Recently (JDE plugin 1.5.0+), I have been using the Eclipse **Run -> Debug As -> BlackBerry Simulator** choice, or the special BlackBerry plugin Debug icon:

[image]

When I start either of these ways, it does not ask me to make another choice.

Note that I don't see the hot swap (restart app without a full simulator restart) feature work correctly on all simulators, even those with OS > 5.0, if I use Eclipse.

Here are some more references on running and debugging within Eclipse:

http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/35144/Testing_a_BB_app_with_BB_smartphone_sim_1889924_11.jsp

By the way, [an older (plugin 1.3) version of that document](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/23671/Using_the_BB_menu_1382991_11.jsp) mentions **BlackBerry Simulator (running)**, while the newer version (1.5) does not.  So, maybe RIM no longer intends for you to use that choice (?).

http://devblog.blackberry.com/2009/08/how-to-set-up-a-lightning-fast-blackberry-smartphone-simulator/