# BlackBerry Simulator not reflecting code changes - needs restart for every change

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

I am using BlackBerry `SDK 5.0.0.36` on *eclipse*

whenever i am doing any changes i need to restart the simulator

i want to run simulator only once and dont wanna restart it again n again for little changes

i refer to this thread in stackoverflow.com -> "[View changes without restarting Blackberry simulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072928/view-changes-without-restarting-blackberry-simulator)"

i follow the given procedure in above thread but still my simulator not making it

i also tried it in BlackBerry `SDK 6.0 and 7.1` . . .but i am still fighting with same problem

Comment: Hot-swap functionality still has bugs. It usually works for me but only in a few simulators, but in other ones I always get a `ControlledAccessException`, or in debug mode it doesn't attach, so I have to restart frequently. These bugs probably won't be fixed ever now that RIM is busy with BB10.

Answer (score 0):

As Mister Smith says, this functionality is not highly reliable.  Sometimes it works, and sometimes not.

However, one fixable problem that I encounter somewhat often is that permissions on the JDE plugin folders get restricted so that the BlackBerry simulator cannot write out the proper files to perform hot swapping.

I can often fix this in Windows explorer by going to the root folder for Eclipse (you could probably just go to the JDE plugin folder, if you're concerned about opening up permissions too much).  In Windows Explorer, right-click and select **Properties**.  I then uncheck the **Read-only** checkbox.  Then, use the **Security** tab and make sure that your user account has **Full control** for that directory, **and** all of its subdirectories.

I will usually also just transfer ownership of the entire Eclipse directory tree to my user account (e.g. HOSTNAME\username).  Do that with the **Advanced** button on the **Security** tab.

Also, [have a look at this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12101394/119114) and this [BlackBerry support forum thread on the topic of hot swap file permissions](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/Can-t-use-Hot-swap-even-on-latest-BB-Eclipse-plugin/td-p/1651419)